# Drupal 6 Migration: Files not showing?

Tags: media

I am creating a dev site from production and I read the migration guide and it's basically -- export database, rsync files. So, I cleared the cache (drush cc all) and also turned off Clean URLS because that was suggested in the guide.

I then proceeded to export the database & web directory & files... structure originally;

```
/home/drupal
/home/drupalfiles
MySQL DB
```

I decided to change the locations...

```
/var/www/html/drupal
/var/www/html/drupalfiles
```

However, all the images are now displaying with an 'x'. When I right click on the image, it says it's looking for files in /system/files ... which, I have a symbolic link in /sites/default/all for files to drupal_files (which wasn't needed on production, btw). Even then, I don't know why it's trying to look in a directory called system.

The file-system settings is listed as 'files' on production and dev. So, I have no idea what's going on :( .. in the database, files are listed as /files/.

So frustrating :(!
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using symlinks, you'll have to allow that in your .htaccess file.

Comment: even though it's the wrong answer, I will edit it to LOOK like an answer.

Comment: And I'll adjust my response to say; FollowSymLinks is indeed enabled in the .htaccess file.